# Webform - trying to set submit handler

Tags: 7, webforms

On a Drupal 7 Webform I've added a button using a markup field like this:

```
<button name="get" value="" type="submit" class="primary-submit submit" id="get">
Get Address
</button>
```

I am directing it to a submit handler like this:

```
function new_webform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_88') {
    $form['submitted']['name']['get']['#submit'][]='new_webform_get_submit';
    dpm($form);
  }
}
```

I can tell the button `#submit` is being changed, but the whole form is submitted instead of executing the handler code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot your code snippets =\

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the form was not actually being submitted but the custom handler was not being processed because the form validation was failing. I disabled it with

```
$form['submitted']['name']['get']['#limit_validation_errors']=array();
```

and now the handler works.

Answer (score 1):

In a general scenario, to add a custom submit handler to any Drupal form you can implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_form_id_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

you will have to add the submit handler in the #submit array, something like this,

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit_handler'; //this function will accept $form and $form_state as args.
```

same can be done for #validate if you want a extra validate handler.

Cheers.